# What is the state of a new object in DynamoDB immediately after the client application is returned a 200 OK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to learn how writes/updates work internally in DynamoDB. This is what I could find.

[AWS Tutorial Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)

"When your application writes data to a DynamoDB table and receives an HTTP 200 response (OK), all copies of the data are updated. The data will eventually be consistent across all storage locations, usually within one second or less."

For ex: If my DynamoDB has 50 partitions and it is replicated across 3 availability zones in a region, what happens in DynamoDB

```
After it receives an API request to create an item
After it sends the 200 OK response to the client
```

I would really appreciate any document that talks about this or hear from you directly.

Thanks

Comment: good read: http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2007/10/amazons_dynamo.html

Answer (score 0):

Dynamodb as per [this](https://youtu.be/oz-7wJJ9HZ0) replicates its data in 3 availability zones within the region.

So the question is how it manages the availability of the data.

[image]

Assume there is one receiver which will receive the request from the users.

The receiver for `write request` will have `m/n` value for consistency of data.

`n` is the number of availability zones

`m` would be ((n+1)/2) to maintain consistency.

In this case, it is 2/3.

Now when a receiver receives any request it will send the command to write data to all 3 zones but will wait for 2 zones to respond. When 2 of the zones has written the value the receiver will send 200 OK to user without waiting for zone 3 to respond.

Let say that user now immediately want to retrieve the data which was written.

For `read request` the receiver will use `1/(number of availability zones)`, In this case it is 1/3.

So receiver will request all the zone for data, Let say that zone A respond, This respond will be immediately sent to user.

Assuming 2/3 write request the data is stored in Zone A and Zone B currently, Zone C is still not updated.

Now when we read data if Zone A or B respond then we will have the value if Zone C respond then it will result in not found, this is the reason AWS say dynamoDB is eventual consistent.

When we query data with strongly consistent read, the value change to 2/3 which will make sure that updated value will be sent to user because at a time 2 availability zone will have the newest value

**Note:** This is just a simplified explanation and I am not associated with Amazon, they might be using some other things behind the scene.

Hope that helps